# Forwarding Docker container port from 8002 to 443 not working

Tags: iptables, docker, port-forwarding

I am not really familiar with iptables and all the nuances of the different rules. I am in the process of learning but I need this expedited which is why I'm asking here.

I am running a WebLogic container inside Docker on an AWS EC2 instance. The container is running using `docker run -d -p 8002:8002 weblogic`. I didn't build the image so there are some things that must stay. I need the WebLogic server to be accessible from the outside on port 443 due to network restrictions, even though it is built to be access through port 8002.

I've tried various iptables rules but none of them are successfully forwarding. The container is still accessible on 8002 even with the rules forwarding 8002 -> 443 in place.

Running `RHEL 7.3` and the Dockerfile is built for iptables, not firewalld. Some of this stuff I have no control over so I have to work with what I have.

One of the iptables commands I tried was:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8002 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:443
```

Note: I do know to run `service iptables save`. I can verify the rules exist using `iptables -S`.

EDIT: Here are my iptables rules currently

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT  
-P FORWARD ACCEPT  
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT  
-N DOCKER  
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION  
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT  
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT  
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT  
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited  
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION  
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER  
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT  
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT  
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited  
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT  
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8002 -j  ACCEPT  
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **should not** change internally running container port without rebuilding `Docker` image. `EXPOSE` command at `Dockerfile` level is responsible for exposing container's port. You can inspect exposed container ports with command

```
docker inspect <image-name>
```

As documentation says, `weblogic` server runs on `TCP/8002` by default.
So, I assume you want to have your container to be accessible on `443`, you need to type:

```
docker run -d -p 443:8002 weblogic
```

It just `NAT`-s `TCP/443` (on host level) ->`TCP/8002` (container namespace level).   You can see that in `iptables` as well.

```
iptables -t nat -L
```

It will be visible with:

```
docker ps
```

You will see the following text: `0.0.0.0:443->127.0.0.1:8002`

Next step. You need to add firewall's (`iptables` specificly) rule to allow traffic on `TCP/443`.

So:

```
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

With that you will configure your system's firewall allow traffic to `TCP/443`.

One more thing is missing. 
You need to configure security group associated with EC2 to allow connections to `TCP/443`.

Remember, that such deployment cannot be treated as production ready. It misses many things starting from security and certificates management, ending with service auto-restarting.

References:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/
- http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/

Comment: Need to test in production environment but seems to work. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Greg Look at my edit please. You cannot treat this deployment as production read.

Comment: Duly noted. I should clarify this is like half production, half development and on top of a hardened OS. Anyways, I will work with the network security folks to resolve their concerns. Much appreciated.